# Android: custom Facebook integration

Tags: java, android, facebook

I need some advice for this matter...
I used the facebook android sdk to create an integration with facebook from my application...I followed this tutorial:
http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

I would need to implement authentication in one activity and the function postToWall in another.... after authentication i want to send post simply by pressing a button but in other activity, different from that where i do authentication.

is it possible? or with the SDK I'm forced to do everything together in the same activity?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You will get a access token which you can send to the next activity. Use getAccessToken() and setAccessToken().

Here is an example that even saves the needed data: [Contact-Picture-Sync](https://github.com/heinrisch/Contact-Picture-Sync/blob/master/src/heinrisch/contact/picture/sync/Main.java)

Answer (score 0):

you need to install an extension, similar to the core Android SDK, but no, here is what you need to do:

1.) go to github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

2.) download the facebook directory ONLY! The other directories are only examples.

3.) Put the files from the src (you can copy the drawables too, if you want to) in the package, you are currently working with

4.) You are good to go, you can use the facebook "SDK"

see also this example https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook download it , it is working example provided by facebook

Answer (score 0):

just to provide an alternative answer, there's other ways of implementing sharing on Android.

It allows for more sharing options (like Twitter, QR-Barcodes, blogging and whatnot) without having to deal with the facebook android sdk.

What you would use is a "share" intent, like so:

```
String title = "My thing"; // used if you share through email or channels that require a headline for the content, always include this or some apps might not parse the content right

String wallPost = "Hey - check out this stuff: http://link.com "; // the content of your wallpost

String shareVia = "Share this stuff via"; // the headline for your chooser, where the phones avaliable sharing mechanisms are offered. 

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");


shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);

shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, wallPost);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, shareVia));
```

This is by far the preferred solution on Android if you're looking for simple sharing, as it makes your app future-compatible with new services. And more lean and flexible for the user too, as there's little to no friction from hitting the share button to posting content.

It can also be seen in this blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html

I hope you can use this for your project.